# How to set secure and httponly attributes on Symfony 4 session

Tags: php, symfony, session

I would like to create a secure PHP session in Symfony 4

I looked for informations in the [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html) and [API documentation](http://api.symfony.com/4.1/index.html) but could not find any reference to my problem.

In plain PHP I used to do the following to create a secure PHP session:

```
$session_name = 'session';
$secure = true;
$httponly = true;

$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params(
  $cookieParams["lifetime"], 
  $cookieParams["path"], 
  $cookieParams["domain"], 
  $secure, 
  $httponly
);

session_name($session_name);
session_start();
```

How do you do something similar in Symfony 4 ? the following code does not work:

```
$session->set('lifetime', 0);
$session->set('secure', true);
$session->set('httponly', true);
```

Comment: Everything is in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html). You are not meant to run the session by yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "the following code does not work"? Do you have an error, a log? I think you could set it in the `$options` parameter.

Comment: @AnthonyB I mean that it only sets session key/values data but does not change the settings

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session

Comment: @Cerad thanks a bunch, makes sense now; I have to configure it in the `framework.yaml`. You should post an answer and I'll accept it to help others

Comment: You can go ahead and post your own answer once you have it working.  I don't like posting code without testing and I'm too lazy to setup a project for this.

Comment: well, it works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed by sam and with the correct [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session)

In the Symfony framework, these options should be set in the `framework.yaml`

```
    session:
       handler_id: ~
       cookie_secure: true
       cookie_httponly: true
```