# Why can't I see cookie parameters after I log in?

Tags: symfony, session, cookies

I'm working on making a Symfony website secure. I have taken a look at this page: [How to set secure and httponly attributes on Symfony 4 session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750185/how-to-set-secure-and-httponly-attributes-on-symfony-4-session)

and applied the suggested change into framework.yaml:

```
session:
   handler_id: ~
   cookie_secure: true
   cookie_httponly: true
```

When I log in, in the network tab I see three instances of Set-Cookie. The first is a cookie removal, having secure and HttpOnly attributes. The second is a cookie creation, where the cookie identifier has the secure and HttpOnly attributes. The third is setting some parameters in an HTTP-encoded manner, this one also has the secure and HttpOnly attributes. So far so good. However, when I go to any page, I have a Cookie attribute among the Request Headers which has the same identifier as the one which was created earlier, but the secure and HttpOnly attributes are not specified.

So, when I log in and the cookie is created I have the attributes I expect, but later, on visiting separate pages I no longer see them. Why is the secure and HttpOnly attribute not specified on later, after-login Request Headers? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security attributes are set by the server in the *Response* headers and the browser uses them to determine if it has to send the cookie along in the *Request*, but it never sends the attributes themselves, just the cookie value. If you inspect an ajax or unsecure request the cookie header should not appear in the request at all.

You can see some examples in the [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-3.1).